# How to point a root domain or IP to another domains subdomain?

Tags: dns

We are enabling our clients to route their subdomains, like `sub.client1.com` and `sub.client2.com`, to our servers where the clients websites are hosted.

We ask our clients to create CNAME records that points to `our-sub.domain.com`, e.g.:

```
CNAME sub.clientx.com -> our-sub.domain.com
```

We then have an A record that points `our-sub.domain.com` to our web servers IP addresses, like `1.11.111.11` and `2.22.222.22`:

```
A our-sub.domain.com -> [1.11.111.11, 2.22.222.22]
```

Our internal setup can then switch these underlying IP addresses without any changes required in the clients DNS:

```
A our-sub.domain.com -> [3.33.333.33, 4.44.444.44]
```

But what if the clients want to route their root domains to us, like `client1.com` and `client2.com`?

- They can't create a CNAME record for a root domain
- They can't point an A record to our subdomain, because only IP addresses are allowed

Maybe we can solve it by creating a static IP like `0.00.000.00` that clients can route to with a simple A record:

```
A clientx.com -> 0.00.000.00
```

We could then do one of the following:

1:

Re-route to all of our web server IP's with an internally managed A record from `0.00.000.00`, e.g:

```
A 0.00.000.00 -> [1.11.111.11, 2.22.222.22]
```

2:

Re-route `0.00.000.00` to `our-sub.domain.com`, because it is already routing to our web server IP's. I have noticed how for example Shopify asks clients to route their subdomains to a static IP. This static IP then seems to have a PTR record that points the IP to `myshopify.com`. I don't know what then happens internally. But it would go like this:

```
PTR 0.00.000.00 -> our-sub.domain.com
```

Not sure if any of these suggestions are possible.

Any ideas how this could be solved?

Comment: Are you self hosting the DNS or using a provider? Most providers these days support alias records that do what you want.

Comment: This question is not on topic for Stack Overflow. Questions about DNS must be programming related, as per the tag description. This question may work better on [sf] or [networkengineering.se].

Answer (score 0):

I would do this:

1. Ask your client to set an A record to single public IP address under your control.
2. Set up an nginx proxy server on this address and proxy pass requests to your webservers.

Reference: https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/

Note: By doing this, you can easily add also load balancing capabilities:

https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/load-balancer/http-load-balancer/

Comment: Thanks, but this suggestion is solving it with load balancing on a single node, not through DNS routing. The solution I am looking for puts multiple load balancer nodes in play.

Comment: Well, then your client can create multiple A records pointing to different proxy servers. Also would ALIAS type of the record resolve your issue? See https://docs.gandi.net/en/domain_names/faq/record_types/alias_record.html#:~:text=An%20ALIAS%20record%20is%20a,instead%20of%20an%20IP%20address.&text=To%20add%20and%20manage%20these,be%20using%20Gandi's%20LiveDNS%20nameservers.

Comment: Multiple A records pointing directly from the client domain to the web server nodes would require the client to maintain their DNS themselves every time we switched our web server nodes. That is not acceptable. And an ALIAS does not seem to be something that can be set by most DNS hosts. Checked a few ones, and no such options exists in their interfaces.

Comment: The last section of the following article shows how some DNS providers allow this with ALIAS, ANAME, or CNAME (virtual) records. https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/why-cant-a-domain-s-root-be-a-cname-8cbab38e5f5c/